Asterisk returns 401 for all authentication requests
I'm trying to connect/register with my Asterisk server with pjsua, but the server responds with 401.
In pjsua, I enter +a to create a new account
Then, for the SIP URL: sip:192.168.XXX.YYY
For the registrar, same thing.
For auth realm, *
For username, 6001
For password, unsecurepassword
Here's the 401 error (from pjsua):
18:44:15.083            pjsua_acc.c !Acc 0: setting registration..
18:44:15.084           pjsua_core.c  ..TX 500 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=47971 (tdta0x21cbe108) to UDP [REDACTED]:5060:
REGISTER sip:[REDACTED] SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [REDACTED]:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjo2ammy4Tqrg3K8DZqowjvRjS-YnmrXCx
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:[REDACTED]>;tag=qaH4HUiH2JHAu-Hxs.QfT0gnNOQ-RovH
To: <sip:[REDACTED]>
Call-ID: kjwRBsRQPuN2tKncFGbF2ZmbkFffQFMd
CSeq: 47971 REGISTER
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.14.1 Linux-6.9.8/x86_64/glibc-2.39
Contact: <sip:[REDACTED]:5060;ob>
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
18:44:15.084            pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 0: Registration sent
>>> 18:44:15.087           pjsua_core.c  .RX 521 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=47971 (rdata0x7f4274001dd8) from UDP [REDACTED]:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [REDACTED]:5060;rport=5060;received=[REDACTED];branch=z9hG4bKPjo2ammy4Tqrg3K8DZqowjvRjS-YnmrXCx
Call-ID: kjwRBsRQPuN2tKncFGbF2ZmbkFffQFMd
From: <sip:[REDACTED]>;tag=qaH4HUiH2JHAu-Hxs.QfT0gnNOQ-RovH
To: <sip:[REDACTED]>;tag=z9hG4bKPjo2ammy4Tqrg3K8DZqowjvRjS-YnmrXCx
CSeq: 47971 REGISTER
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="asterisk",nonce="1721007855/c72dde7effdfe533f2a7acb9fbaad011",opaque="758e39897f66ee1c",algorithm=MD5,qop="auth"
Server: Asterisk PBX 20.8.1
Content-Length:  0

I've basically copy-pasted the example configuration from the "hello world" section in the asterisk docs.
/etc/asterisk/pjsip.conf:
    [transport-udp]
    type=transport
    protocol=udp
    bind=0.0.0.0

    [6001]
    type=endpoint
    context=from-internal ; BTW -- I changed this to from-external and it still doesn't work
    disallow=all
    allow=ulaw
    auth=6001
    aors=6001

    [6001]
    type=auth
    auth_type=userpass
    password=unsecurepassword
    username=6001

    [6001]
    type=aor
    max_contacts=1

/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf:
    [tests]
    ; Dial 100 for "hello, world"
    exten => 100,1,Answer()
    same  =>     n,Wait(1)
    same  =>     n,Playback(hello-world)
    same  =>     n,Hangup()

    [softphones]
    include => tests

    [unauthorized]

